# Are there some common techniques for Java Web Servers to detect when approaching overload?

Tags: java, performance, server, microservices, resiliency

In a period where microservices become more and more predominant, I was wondering if there are some common techniques by which Java Web Services detect overload before start deteriorating.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there is `One golden rule` (e.g. CPU never has to go above 50%), and it seems a topic where the best heuristic wins.

Online there are several resources pointing out to a X number of CPU, GC pauses, Network IO etc, but I was wondering if there were more scientific studies/documented use cases to catch these signaling.

Comment: I think you'll need to better define what you consider to be "overload" and what "deteriorating" entails, but ime the main technique is to test the system load (similar to 'top' command) and base the "load" on that number.

Comment: You don't do the detection in the service itself.  You use an external monitoring system; e.g. checkmk, nagios, etc.  This is a system / network admin problem not a programming problem.